# Controllers and directives, precedence

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I've been with Angularjs a few days and I'm struggling with a few aspects of it. I'll do my best to try and explain what the issue is, and I'd really appreciate any help anyone can give me about it.

My situation (simplified) is this:

I have a service which loads some info from a json and stores it in an object. It also have some functions to be used for other controllers to retrieve that information.

```
var particServices = angular.module('particServices', []);

particServices.service('particSrv', function() {

  var data = {};

  this.updateData = function(scope) {
    data = // http call, saves in data
  }

  this.getName = function(code) {
    return data.name;
  }

});
```

I have an html page assisted by a controller, which uses a directive board (no params, really simple). This is the controller:

```
var bControllers = angular.module('bControllers', []);

bControllers.controller('bController', ['$scope', 'particSrv', function ($scope, particSrv) {   

$scope.getName = function(code) {   
  return particSrv.getName(code);
};

particSrv.updateData($scope);       

}]);
```

As you can see, the controller makes the call to initialize the object in the service. As this is a singleton, I understand once that info is loaded no other call needs to be make to updateData and that info is available to others using the getters in the service (getName in this case).

I have a really simple directive board (which I simplified here), which uses another directive bio.

angular.module('tsDirectives', [])

```
.directive('board', ['dataSrv', 'particSrv', function(dataSrv, particSrv) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope) {                      

      $scope.getName = function(code) { 
        return particSrv.getName(code);
      };

      dataSrv.updateData($scope, 'board', 'U');                             

    },
    templateUrl: '<div class="board"><div bio class="name" partic="getName(code)"/></div></div>'
};      
}]);
```

And this is the bio directive:

```
angular.module('gDirectives', [])

.directive('bio', function() {  

  return {
    scope: {
      partic: '&'
    },          
    controller: function($scope) {          
      $scope.name = $scope.partic({code: $scope.athid});
    },
    template: '<a ng-href="PROFILE.html">{{name}}</a>'
};      
})
```

Now, what I expected is that in the bio directive the info retrieved from party was displayed, but apparently this directive is processed before the partic is initialized in the main controller.

I was under the impression that even though this information was still not loaded when the directive is processed, as soon as the service finishes and the info is ready, automagically it would appear in my directive, but that does not seem to work like that. I've been reading about $watch and $digest, but I fail to see why (and if) I would need to call them manually to fix this.

Any hint will be much appreciated. I could provide more technical details if needed.

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. We can't tell you how to fix code with only a description of it.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I was afraid the code could overcomplicate the question. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive will initialise when app is loaded and user opens the page where that directive is, if you have some property that is set later (from api for example), it will update that property in directive but that directive will not be reinitialised ($scope.partic({code: $scope.athid}) wont be called).

If you want for directive to wait for initialisation you should use ng-if. Something like this:

```
<div data-directive-name data-some-property="someProperty" data-ng-if="someProperty"></div>
```

In this case directive will be initialised when (if) you have some value in $scope.someProperty. But this is not very good if you can have false values for someProperty.
In that case you would need to use some kind of loaded flag.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ng-if will not load the data if the property is false, which might be ok, but I need it to load it once the data is loaded in the service and the property becomes true.

Comment: It will be loaded as soon as someProperty have any "truthy" value.

Comment: Thanks, @Ivan, that worked.
`<div bio class="name" partic="getName(code)" ng-if="isCodeLoaded()"/>`
I just thought that behaviour was implicit to angular, as I'm using a property in the model that is being updated later on.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included "particServices" as a dependency in other modules which use the services of "particServices". Your modules should look like:

```
var bControllers = angular.module('bControllers', ['particServices']);

angular.module('tsDirectives', ['particServices']);

angular.module('gDirectives', ['particServices']);
```

Comment: I don´t think that's a problem. I manage all modules in app.js file.

Comment: Manage? And may I know how? Used $injector?

Comment: My main application uses ng-app="myApp", which loads all modules by injection. Maybe I'm wrong, but there seems to be no problems with the app finding the right modules when they are needed.

Comment: That sounds interesting! Something i was not aware of. Can you please share the code for dependency injection, for entirely reference purpose?

Comment: I have this in my main html, `<div ng-app="myApp">` and then I have a myApp.js file with all the modules used, as in `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['module1','module2','module3']);`